# test if there where no results from mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, database, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm writing a login system and I'm having some trouble with error handling if the username they entered isn't in my database. I'm starting to suspect it is something with my prepared statements.

When the user submits the form I call my check login function that takes in the users info, sanitizes it, and then uses it to pull out information for them in the database.

A bit of my code:

```
$db = getConnection();// Function that creates a new mysqli db connection

    if($db->connect_error){
            echo mysqli_connect_error();
            exit();
    }

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT password, client, rootFolder from Users WHERE username = ?");
    //$sanUsername is created from the username that is passed into the function
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$sanUsername);// Binds the sanitized username to the ?
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;

    $stmt->bind_result($pw,$client,$folder);


    if($num_rows > 0){ 
            checkPassword stuff
    }else{
      failedLogin();
    }
```

My problem is failedLogin() is never getting called if the username isn't in the database. It gets called if the username is correct but the password is incorrect though.

I'm assuming it must be something with the way I'm doing my prepared statement but I can't figure out what could be causing it. Will it break out of the code if there was no results returned?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: fyi: binding a parameter doesn't "sanitize" anything

Comment: what do you get when you do this: var_dump($num_rows); exit; right before the $stmt->bind_result() line for the username present and not present cases ?

Comment: I know. I sanitize in a different part of my code. I tried simplifying the concept I was trying to do.

Comment: I get: int(1) if the username exists in the DB and nothing is shown if the username doesn't exist. It just reloads the login page again. That's why I suspected it was something with my prepared statement approach since it seems to break before it gets to the $num_rows assignment.